# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el dataframe resultante de estimar un modelo logit binomial con glm?

Tags: r, dataframe, anova, glm

Tengo un `dataframe` con varios **valores faltantes** y quiero realizar un **análisis de la varianza** (ANOVA) para comparar dos modelos **logit binomial**:

- **Modelo A**: contiene un set de variables.
- **Modelo B**: Contiene las mismas variables que el Modelo A **más 3 variables de estudio**.

Importamos los datos:

**Modelo A:**

```
modelo_logit <- glm(SAP ~ sexo + edad + peso + niv_est + enf_cron + sit_lab + 
                       frec_act_fis + ingreso_eq + GHQ_12, 
                       data = datos_modelo, family = binomial(link = "logit"),na.action = "na.omit")
```

**Modelo B:**

```
modelo_logit_viv <- glm( SAP ~ sexo + edad + niv_est + enf_cron + sit_lab +
                                  frec_act_fis + ingreso_eq + GHQ_12 + 
                                  n_dormitorios + cont_indus + delincuencia, # variables de estudio 
                        data = datos_modelo, family = binomial(link = "logit"),na.action = "na.omit")
```

Para poder realizar un **ANOVA** ejecuto: `anova(modelo_logit,modelo_logit_viv)`

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error in anova.glmlist(c(list(object), dotargs), dispersion = dispersion,  : 
>     models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset

**Ambos modelos deben ser ajustados por el mismo por el mismo set de datos**, pero como hay varios valores faltantes, **el modelo B tiene más `NA's` que el modelo A** (ya que el modelo B contiene más variables que incrementan el número de observaciones que han de eliminarse con respecto al modelo A).

Mi pregunta entonces es: ¿Cómo puedo obtener el dataframe que se emplea en el modelo B (`modelo_logit_viv`) para poder estimar el modelo A (`modelo_logit`) y tener así **el mismo dataframe para estimar ambos modelos** y efectuar a continuación el ANOVA? Tiene que haber algún elemento dentro del objeto generado por `glm(*)` que contenga el `dataframe` que se ha empleado para estimar una vez eliminado los `NA's`, pero no lo encuentro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El elemento que buscas se llama `model`, aquí un ejemplo copiado de la ayuda de `glm`:

```
set.seed(2020)
counts <- c(18,17,15,20,10,20,25,13,12)
outcome <- gl(3,1,9)
treatment <- gl(3,3)
random_with_na <- sample(c(1, 2, NA), 9, replace = TRUE)
d.AD <- data.frame(treatment, outcome, counts, random_with_na)

m1 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment, data = d.AD, family = poisson(), na.action = "na.omit")
m2 <- glm(counts ~ outcome + treatment + random_with_na,  data = d.AD, family = poisson(), na.action = "na.omit")

m1$model
m2$model

> m1$model
  counts outcome treatment
1     18       1         1
2     17       2         1
3     15       3         1
4     20       1         2
5     10       2         2
6     20       3         2
7     25       1         3
8     13       2         3
9     12       3         3
> m2$model
  counts outcome treatment random_with_na
1     18       1         1              2
2     17       2         1              1
3     15       3         1              2
4     20       1         2              2
5     10       2         2              2
```

Como se puede apreciar los datos del modelo 2 (que agrega una variable nueva con `NA's`) tiene menos filas que los datos originales, por que justamente en este caso se omiten las filas completas.

Ahora, con respecto a lo que intentas hacer, entiendo que tienes solo dos caminos posibles a seguir:

1. Imputar los valores `NA`
2. Generar un `data.frame` únicamente con las filas que no tienen `NA`en alguna de las variables de interés, por ejemplo `na.ommit(tu_dataframe[, columnas_para_los_modelos])` y el `data.frame` resultante sería el que alimentaría los dos modelos.